# Chef - Installing zenoss but HTTP Request Returned 500 Internal Server Error: Connection refused - connect(2)

Tags: chef-infra, zenoss

I am trying to install zenoss on ubuntu using chef.

When I run chef-client I get this error.  I do not know how to resolve.

```
Fri, 06 Apr 2012 18:01:44 +0000] INFO: Loading cookbooks [apache2, apt, build-essential, monitor_base, openssh, openssl, python, yum, zenoss]
[Fri, 06 Apr 2012 18:01:44 +0000] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 500 Internal Server Error: Connection refused - connect(2)
[Fri, 06 Apr 2012 18:01:44 +0000] ERROR: Server returned error for http://106.187.89.115:4000/search/node?q=recipes:zenoss%5C:%5C:server&sort=X_CHEF_id_CHEF_X%20asc&start=0&rows=1000, retrying 1/5 in 3s
[Fri, 06 Apr 2012 18:01:47 +0000] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 500 Internal Server Error: Connection refused - connect(2)
[Fri, 06 Apr 2012 18:01:47 +0000] ERROR: Server returned error for http://106.187.89.115:4000/search/node?q=recipes:zenoss%5C:%5C:server&sort=X_CHEF_id_CHEF_X%20asc&start=0&rows=1000, retrying 2/5 in 6s
[Fri, 06 Apr 2012 18:01:53 +0000] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 500 Internal Server Error: Connection refused - connect(2)
[Fri, 06 Apr 2012 18:01:53 +0000] ERROR: Server returned error for http://106.187.89.115:4000/search/node?q=recipes:zenoss%5C:%5C:server&sort=X_CHEF_id_CHEF_X%20asc&start=0&rows=1000, retrying 3/5 in 16s
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the solr startup.  On your Chef server, make sure chef-solr is running.  I suspect it isn't.  Most likely this is an issue with permissions.  Make sure that both /var/run/chef and /var/log/chef are owned by chef.